# How to achieve silent login and get code/token from google using OAuth 2

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, postman

I am new to google oath ,

Referring to the documentation of google

While i Generate the login URL
example

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
redirect_uri=http://www.mywebapp.com/oauth2callback&
response_type=code&
client_id=104608secret-secret-secret-secret.apps.googleusercontent.com&
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&
approval_prompt=force&
access_type=offline
```

This **redirects** to an **accept** page showing google **email Id**

When the user clicks on “Accept” google will redirect the user to your given redirect_url

when i use chrome and 
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ 
Because it redirects screen to accept.
everything will work fine.

But when i use postman it wont return the "access code" of google

What am i making wrong in the url parameters  .

I have to create rest service using the above url.

I have searched So for 
[How to get dummy google access token to test oauth google api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657190/how-to-get-dummy-google-access-token-to-test-oauth-google-api)
[How can I verify a Google authentication API access token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359472/how-can-i-verify-a-google-authentication-api-access-token?rq=1)
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/google-oauth-2-enable-your-application-to-access-data-from-a-google-user/

But non explained about silent login to get token without accept screen

Answer (score 0):

Your callback url receives a "code".

Then you need to exchange your "code" for an access token.

https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2